# Can BLE peripheral mode trigger the disconnection or refuse to connect?

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Here's our situation.  We have a machine vending machine run in peripheral mode and mobile runs in central mode. When the mobile is close to the vending machine, it triggers the connection and start to communicate.  But as far as I know, the peripheral mode can only connect to one device at a time just considering bluetooh 4.0, so if there's someone who wants to make a trick stands around  our vending machine and connects to it all the time, no one else can connect the vending machine.  Am I right?

My question is

1. How to avoid this situation.  Is it possible for the vending machine to refuse the connection or to trigger the disconnection when it founds that the connection is invalid (triggered by other app)?
2. I have heard something like multipoint bluetooth.  So how much can the multi be, can it be like 100 so that it may solve the problem.
3. I found a similar situation in paypal beacon. https://devblog.paypal.com/how-does-paypal-beacon-work/ it says the beacon is running in peripheral mode.  I am wondering how do they avoid these invalid connections.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for a slave to dump connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, the central device(mobile device) initiating connection, it will act as Master and the other end device(vending machine) will act as slave.

According to Bluetooth 4.1 specification, a slave can have multiple masters.
So, more than one mobile device can connect to the single LE device.

Comment: if just considering bluetooth 4.0, it still will be a problem that other device connects the vending machine or beacon and occupy it all the time. am i right?

Comment: Yes. In 4.0, a slave cannot have multiple masters, cannot connect to multiple devices at the same time.

Comment: can the slave trigger the disconnection or refuse to connect?  Since I found that paypal beacon acts as a slave as well, I wondering what will happen if all the beacons are connected..

Comment: I am not sure whether a slave can send disconnection request or not.
But in BLE, the connection is disconnected when there is no data transmission for a period of time(supervision timeout).

Comment: I see, thank you. I will let the question open to see if there's any other ideas.

Comment: Your welcome...
If the vending machine is of some third party vendor(means, vending machine is not under your control), then you cannot forcefully make it to disconnect the connection with  other tricky device as it has to follow the BLE specifications.

Comment: The vending machine can be customised so I am trying to find out if it is possible do some modification either at application level or connection level like l2cap, etc.

Comment: Okay. If you have access to manage the vending machine end code then you can disconnect the device by closing the GATT connection after data has been transferred, no need to maintain connection after data transmission.
If you want to block requests from certain devices then you can add those device addresses to the whitelist using "LE Add Device To White List Command"

Comment: your welcome. if you find the answer/comment is useful then please upvote :P

Comment: sorry, I can only accept it but cannot upvote it for the poor reputation:(

Comment: Okay.. Thats fine.. :)

Comment: @Vinodh I would add that to your answer - it's a good solution if the vending machine/peripheral can be modified