# How to disconnect to BLE peripheral manually?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Bluetooth peripheral is disconnected if it go out of vicinity of Ble central (My Android device)...
I want to disconnect it manually by button... Is there any method in android to disconnect Ble peripheral???

Ble peripheral also disconnects, if supervision timeout occurs. But i want to disconnect it instantly because if it is in connected mode then it can't advertise itself...

In Ble core Specification, link layer control packet for disconnecting the connection is "0X02 LL_TERMINATE_IND"... How to call this in android?????? Any Help???

Edit: I am using Bluetooth v4.0. I read in this post [Can BLE peripheral mode trigger the disconnection or refuse to connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235379/can-ble-peripheral-mode-trigger-the-disconnection-or-refuse-to-connect) that Bluetooth v4.1 peripheral can connect to more than one central, so as per my understanding it means that it will advertise itself even it is connected to one Ble central (Android device). But i am using BLE v4.0 and i want to disconnect to peripheral for connecting to it again...??? How to disconnect manually to the Ble peripheral???? Any help???

Answer (score 0):

`mConnectGatt.disconnect()`, This is what I wanted...!